# How can I add sublime-like key mappings to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, key-bindings

It's been a pain to type code in eclipse, sublime text makes everything much more easy. I can't seem to find anything. I can only find "How to add eclipse-like key bindings for sublime". I doesn't seem possible can anyone help?

Comment: What keyboard shortcuts do you want in particular? Take into account that some sublimetext features might not even be supported in eclipse

Comment: @marianosimone stuff like: multiple selection, multiple cursors, multiple row editing... mainly

Answer (score 1):

`Eclipse` doesn't provide all the same features as `sublimetext`, so you might not be able to map everything you want. There are, however, a couple of things you might try:

- [eclipse-multicursor](https://github.com/caspark/eclipse-multicursor): A (somehow) abandoned plugin. From the project:

  > implemented under the covers by using Eclipse linked mode editing (similar to existing "rename in file" functionality), so you can't move the cursors outside the initial selection areas, and all multiple-cursor-edited-text must be the same string.
- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift/cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to *Toggle block selection*
- Create a key-binding configuration, according to [the docs](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_my_own_key-binding_configuration%3F), setting  o whatever you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

Use [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) IDE instead. I have been using this IDE for over 2 years, before that around 4 years on Eclipse.

You can change your key-map to various options already exist there. Even you can multi-mix various keytabs to make your own, say mixture of Eclipse and sublime.

Here is the full guide for migrating: [Eclipse to Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eclipse.html)